# Are perma-links possible in ExtJS4?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a web-app which lets users look at report data. Sometimes they want to share the results they found with one another.

At the moment, they have to tell their collegues what they have to klick and write to get the same results.

Now they wish for something like the perm-link function in google-maps. They did a bunch of klicks, added filters and what not.

Then they push a button, receive a perm-link, and when another user opens it, he gets the same results.

I know this is a very app-specific requirement, I just want to know if there is any basic mechanism for the base-components of extjs.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it wrong to copy the text of sencha example here, so referenced. Here's the solution: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/history/history.html